# IONIC.None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I know this is a common problem and i know there is 1000 posts about this problem. But none of those solution can't help me (3 pages of google search).

This is my whole error, when i run ionic build ios:

```
017-06-03 10:38:20.065 xcodebuild[1581:16644] WARNING: Failed to load plugin at path: "/Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin", skipping. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_IDEOpenQuicklyPattern
  Referenced from: /Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
 in /Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_IDEOpenQuicklyPattern
  Referenced from: /Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
 in /Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/FuzzyAutocomplete, NSBundlePath=/Users/prolink/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “FuzzyAutocomplete” couldn’t be loaded.}

2017-06-03 10:38:20.095 xcodebuild[1581:16644] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/ry/4bfyljms7xg7g35m70936sph0000gn/T/Baltazar_2017-06-03_10-38-20.094.xcdistributionlogs'.

2017-06-03 10:38:20.258 xcodebuild[1581:16644] [MT] DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/prolink/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.3.1.db).

2017-06-03 10:38:21.773 xcodebuild[1581:16644] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoMap:]: Can't find any applicable signing identities for items: (
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>"
)
Errors={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e2eb940; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='81AA125241451B599B3EA609DADA00F234F5DD9E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3e9d9e00; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e5aa080; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='5DDC62FF944F92C5A1972FB606042398F9ADD32E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=2 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3ea21c40; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}

2017-06-03 10:38:21.774 xcodebuild[1581:16644] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fdb3e60a8e0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e2eb940; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='81AA125241451B599B3EA609DADA00F234F5DD9E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3e9d9e00; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e5aa080; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='5DDC62FF944F92C5A1972FB606042398F9ADD32E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=2 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3ea21c40; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}}

error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e2eb940; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='81AA125241451B599B3EA609DADA00F234F5DD9E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: aps-environment., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3e9d9e00; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7fdb3e5aa080; name='iPhone Developer: Sasa Lackovic (84MFEZ8WT8)', hash='5DDC62FF944F92C5A1972FB606042398F9ADD32E', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7fdb3e9410d0 'com.ionicframework.baltazar277384' '<DVTFilePath:0x7fdb3e583ab0:'/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vukovic\U0301_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/Baltazar.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Baltazar.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=2 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7fdb3ea21c40; portalTeamID='29445VXJ42', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.ionicframework.baltazar277384', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"aps-environment\" = development;\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}}


** EXPORT FAILED **


Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Baltazar.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vuković_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/prolink/Desktop/Filip_Vuković_stafs/Veleuciliste_Baltazar_app finalna/Baltazar/platforms/ios/build/device
```

I try things like: deleting and downloading profiles, Changing Bundle id in xcode(its the same as in config.xml) restarting xcode and mac, generating  new certificats and profiles, running bunch of commands for running the app and copying profiles.  Can somebody help me. pls

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I'm using push notification in my app and i did'nt add it Capabilities on xcode and https://developer.apple.com/.